# Debugging malloc(): memory corruption on new

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a small to medium size application which combines Fortran and C++. The main is written in Fortran, but one module is in c++. This module returns pointers to class objects which are stored on the Fortran size. During the creation on one of these pointers the system is throwing the following error:

```
malloc(): memory corruption

Thread 1 "bc_test" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff4a60801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff4aa9897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff4bd6b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff4ab090a in malloc_printerr (
    str=str@entry=0x7ffff4bd4e0e "malloc(): memory corruption") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff4ab4994 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff4e0bc40 <main_arena>, 
    bytes=bytes@entry=44) at malloc.c:3738
#5  0x00007ffff4ab72ed in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=44) at malloc.c:3065
#6  0x00007ffff50bc298 in operator new(unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000555555578967 in My_Class::My_Class(this=0x7fffffffd4e0, n=11)
    at /home/.../my_class.cpp:20
```

Using gdb I have found that the error is thrown during a call to new. More specifically during a call to new within the constructor of an object being created via new (a basic new call works as expected). The line throwing the error is the following:

```
int* test  = new int[n];
```

in this case n is an integer with n=11.

I don't think that the problem is due to a lack of memory as I have only allocated 2 small class instances and a few basic variables at this point. I also believe this would throw a different error if this were the problem.

Unfortunately I haven't managed to create a MWE. I've now run out of ideas of how to fix this problem. What can cause this error? How can it be debugged beyond finding the line throwing the error?

Other stack overflow results concerning "malloc(): memory corruption" errors are due to accessing unallocated memory however this isn't the case here as it is the allocation call itself which is throwing the error.

Comment: You have corrupted memory at some point between when the program starts and when this happens. Unfortunately, it's impossible to be more specific than that.

Comment: C++ is not always debugging friendly. If UndefinedBehaviour is invoked somewhere in a program by accessing arrays out of bounds or dereferencing dangling pointers (or ...), a crash can occur later even on a nice and correct instruction. I know no *assisted* way of finding UB in a C++ module: you must carefully control all the accesses (except by first removing all the possible warning if some are left)

Comment: So the problem is elsewhere? That makes sense given that this line seems fine. Do you think it can be debugged with valgrind or similar?

Comment: Try to use _address sanitizer_ and/or Valgrind. Also, do you compile without optimizations and with debugging info?

Comment: You are right I was corrupting the memory elsewhere. I have found the error with Valgrind. Thank you everyone :)
If someone want to create an answer suggesting that then I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory corruption errors do not always manifest themselves in the place where the error was committed. As a result the gdb backtrace is often useless for finding the error. Instead a memory analysis/debugging tool such as [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) should be used.